# no puedo conectar mi html cin un php

Tags: php, html, html5

```
<body>
  <form class="form" method="post">
    <center>
      <h1>Cursos Cucei</h1>
      <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
      <input id="v1" placeholder="Usuario">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input  id="v2" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <form>
        <input style="width: 100px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px; #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #999; -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #999; font-weight: bold; background: #e6e6e6; color: #000; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; font-size: 75%;"
          type="button" value="Ingresa" onclick="login()"
        />
      </form>
```

Tengo ese `body`, el botón llama a la función `login()`

```
function login(){
  var usuario=document.getElementById("v1").value;
  var password=document.getElementById("v2").value;
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200){
      if (this.responseText == "0"){
        ons.notification.alert ("No existe usuario")
      }else{
        location.href ="https://proyecto-mario.com/page1.html";  
      }
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","https://proyecto-mario.com/db.php?v1=" + 
    usuario + "&v2=" + password, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Al presionar mi botón no hace nada.

Este es el `db.php`

```
<?php
$usuario = $_GET['v1'];
$password = $_GET['v2'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","id91947_root","ciclo2019","id97_cursoscucei");

$sql="SELECT usuario, password, imagen FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' and password='$password' ";

$retval=(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
$arr = array();
echo '<p class="alert alert-success agileits" role="alert">Captura realizada correctamente!p>';

if(mysqli_num_rows($retval)>0){
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)){
    $arr[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($arr);
}else{
  echo "No existe el usuario";
}
?>
```

Comment: cual es la duda o problema a resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Para empezar por lo que veo estás llamandolo con `GET` cuando necesitas un post, y te recomiendo que uses ajax para conectar al php

```
$.ajax({ url: url,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            $('#div_donde_poner_resultado').html(output);
        },
        error: function(salida) {
            console.log(salida);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

    });
```